# How do I make response from selenium go onto discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, discord

I am running a code that checks if something is in stock and types in stock if it is and OOS if it isn't. I want this to be sent as a message in discord. Here is the original code

```
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import *

OOS = '//*[@id="notifyMe"]'
in_stock = '//*[@id="viewport"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/button'

while True:
    web = webdriver.Chrome()

    web.get('https://www.target.com/p/minecraft-bee-pillow-buddy/-/A-79337175')
    time.sleep(1)

    try:
        instock_button = web.find_element_by_xpath(in_stock).click()
        print("INSTOCK")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("OOS")
    web.quit()
```

I have tried to add something like this

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def test():
    channel = client.get_channel(784163508299890738)
    await channel.send()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    test.start()


client.run(TOKEN)
```

to no success can anyone please help me out!!!

Answer (score 0):

I done the same, as i found out there is no way to just start the event, so you have to do it manually. This means that you have to set a discord function like this:

```
@client.command()  
async def test()  
channel = client.get_channel(784163508299890738)  
#do selenium stuff
await channel.send("whatever you find out with selenium")
```

means you just set the selenium function into the discord command, and then you can start it by typing !test or whatever prefix you set, and it should start.
Edit: i personally worked with Discord.ext, since this is more complete i think, you may want to look into that